# Tableau: Calculated Field (Opted In vs Complete)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report that I need to show 2 columns 1) Opted In which is the total number of callers opted to take the survey, and 2) Complete which is the number of callers who completed the survey.  I was able to accomplish #1, but it is a challenge for #2 since I'm new at Tableau. Appreciate your help.

```
COUNT(IF([Status]=="Complete" THEN [Number of Records] END)
```

Comment: Hard to help. Please show us how your data source is structured (if possible give a glimpse of it), show which fields has the information you want, and explain better what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Inox that it is hard to answer your question without seeing the actual data structure you're working with, nor the results you're expecting.

That being said, I did encounter similar situations and here's the calculation I would use to accomplish what I think you'd like to do.

```
SUM(IIF([Status]=="Complete", 1, 0))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did it this way COUNT(IF([Status]="Complete") THEN [Number of Records] END)